# Spritekit/swift custom fonts outline, shadow, etc

Tags: swift, fonts

I've used Cocos2d before and a program called bmGlyph to create custom fonts with Objective C. However with Spritekit and swift I don't know if I can create a bitmap font, and if I can, I honestly don't know how to do it with swift.

I've searched around but I can't find any relevant documentation. Sorry if I'm reposting. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you coding for iOS or OSX ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm coding for iOS